# Updating Database phpmyadmin with codeigniter4 or codeigniter3

Tags: php, html, css, web, codeigniter-4

Im sorry im new in CI4 or CI3,

I want to update my database with a form. But it can not update where i want to, even i put code where in it, if i delete the where code, they will update all of my record in my database, please ive been reading the documentation of CI4 and i still cant understand why my code can not detect the where code.

here's my full controllers code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $data['title'] = 'My Profile';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where(
            'user',
            ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')]
        )->row_array();

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar');
        $this->load->view('user/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where(
            'user',
            ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')]
        )->row_array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'required|trim');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() ==  false) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('templates/topbar');
            $this->load->view('user/edit');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            //update data name / bio
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $bio = $this->input->post('bio');
            $data = array(
                "name" => $name,
                "bio"  => $bio,
            );
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user', $data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" style="text-align:center;" role="alert">
    Your profile has been updated!</div>');
            redirect('user/edit');
        }

    }
}
```

And i dont use any models :/

Comment: Well first of all, it appears that you are using CodeIgniter 3. So, i would be reading the CodeIgniter 3 Documentation.

Comment: You have a problem where you are able to change the email which you are using as the "where" in your update. So what is why that isn't working. Do you have an ID or some primary key which is NOT one of the fields you are changing? Can you add to your question, your Database Table please.

Comment: Also, could you add the code for your form please.

Comment: This is Works! thank u so much, so the problem is i should use my primary key to code where, which is 'id', not email. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

The comment from TimBrownlaw below is answered my question. I should go with primary key in my table in database, not using email column.

New code:

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$bio = $this->input->post('bio');
$data = array(
                "name" => $name,
                "bio"  => $bio,
            );

$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('user');
```